# Tried running a block tester twice, coolant got into the tube

Tags: dodge, radiator, head-gasket, coolant-leak

I read the instructions. I used a turkey blaster to remove the coolant from the radiator hose. The first time, while I was pumping it, it seemed to be going as advetised until the coolant got in, so I removed it, shut the car off and saw the coolant had rise back up quite a bit. I washed out the block tester, dried it and tried again. Repeat steps, had used the turkey blaster again, but this time, I didn't even touch the thing, I left the block tester in the radiator opening then took my attention off for a moment, looked back, and the whole thing was full of coolant and started squirting out the top. I shut the car off, checked and now the hose is completely empty. What is going off here?
I am checking in the first place because a few days ago, I got home and while unloading, noticed coolant spilling all out underneath.

This is a 2001 Dodge Dakota

Comment: Are you running the engine? most pressure testers have the means to provide the pressure externally so tests can be done over long periods. What is a turkey blaster? Does it put it into orbit?

Comment: Yes the engine was running. And for turkey blaster, it's just a liquid dropper used for food, I didn't know turkey blaster was the term for it until I started researching this block tester so I just went with it.

Comment: So you mean "turkey baster"? a kitchen aid to spray juices over the turkey during cooking...

Comment: Oh, baster... easy mistake I guess